# Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian Jessie Lite

Tags: usb-power

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B+ with an SD card with Raspbian Jessie Lite operating system. I have also installed a program that allows the Pi to become hotspot every time it starts.

When I plug the power to USB from a computer to my Raspberry Pi, I have solid red light. Everything is fine I can connect it through SSH and Wi-Fi.

But when I plug the Raspberry Pi into a wall outlet, it lights a solid green light and I cannot get a connection from the Pi.

Comment: What's the rating on the USB adapter your using?

Comment: lol i just change the usb adapter and now it work. lol thank you

Comment: In which case could you post an answer explaining what you did and mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0):

Low voltage. Your adapter probably can't handle a Pi. Go get a better one, preferably one that can handle 2A.